# Order result objects by distance using GeoDjango

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango, nearest-neighbor

I use GeoDjango to retreive all objects nearest by a position. I use `distance_lte` function. I use `Postgres + PostGIS`.

```
user.objects.filter(userLocation__position__distance_lte=(userLocation.position, D(km=15))
```

Is possible to order the result by distance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

```
user.objects.filter(userLocation__position__distance_lte=(userLocation.position, D(km=15)).distance(userLocation.position).order_by('distance')
```